# How can I use my old cellphones camera on my arduino robot?

Tags: sensors, pins

The pins are so small I dont know which pin needs to go to the which pin socket and if t's compatible or not. I have the selfie camera of Xperia Z phone and a Arduino Uno r3.

Comment: If you need a camera, chances are that an "arduino" is the wrong tool for your job, or at least *that part of it*.   Consider a more serious "computer" for high levels tasks, and potentially an Arduino-type device as a motion control delegate if that can't handle such things itself.

Answer (score 2):

> How can i use my old cellphones camera on my arduino robot?

No! Even if you got all the details on the camera there are too many limitations with the Arduino for any serious application. You will need more memory and processing power.

Answer (score 2):

Camera modules usually talk a protocol called CSI-2 or CSI-3. That's the Camera Serial Interface protocol.

It transfers very large amounts of data very fast. More data than a little Arduino can cope with.  For instance, a current typical mobile phone camera is measured in multiples of megapixels. Each pixel takes 3 bytes to represent at 24-bit, so say you have a 2 megapixel camera that would be in excess of 6 megabytes of data per image.  To put that into perspective the Arduino Uno has 2kB of RAM.

So no there is no way you will be able to directly interface a mobile phone camera to any of the microcontroller based Arduinos. That's not to say that something might not be able to be hacked on to one of the new-fangled things they try and pass off as Arduinos these days but are actually some strange SoC made by Intel. You're very much on your own with those though...

There are camera modules available aimed at the Arduino, but they are not directly readable by the Arduino due to lack of memory. They do, though, generally have a UART interface for controlling the camera, and then a separate streaming interface (often with a FIFO buffer to access the data slowly) for grabbing a snapped picture. The Arduino can't really do much with that data other than save it to an SD card or pass it on to a computer through USB, so they're pretty pointless really.